# JSON.NET Deserializing derived class if base class is in other assembly

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this situation where App and UI is in others class libraries.

```
namespace App;
public class BaseClass
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

namespace UI;
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  public string B { get; set; }
}

namespace UI;
public void MyMethod()
{
   string json = @"{"A": "some value", "B": "other value"}";
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DerivedClass>(json);
}
```

After calling peace of code below variable `deserialized.B = null`. If I move derived class to same namespace/assembly as BaseClass then `deserialized.B = "other value"`. Is it bug or exists some workaround?

Comment: What version of Json.NET?

Comment: Newtonsoft Json 10.0.2

Comment: I think you're probably missing something in your example: if the base assembly is not referenced, the derived class cannot be loaded. And if the base is referenced, Json.Net shouldn't have problems deserializing it. Could you refine your example, or try by yourself to test a simplified scenario? The code you posted doesn't even compile, so I think it's just there for the sake of exposition, but possibly you're interpreting ther results in the wrong way.

Comment: I tried simplify example as possible because I'm working on a big project. Referencing assemblies is correctly set.

Comment: I also tried custom `JsonConverter` for be sure that will be use correct type but without success.